# Existing Word mailmerge documents, I want to replace path of linked Excel datasource using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, path, datasource, edit

I have a number of Word documents that use Excel spreadsheets as their data source for mail merging. The documents have been moved to an alternate server path now and when the Word documents are opened they can't find the original Excel data file and prompt for the file. This can be fixed manually just by browsing to the new location.

However, I would like to write a PowerShell script to go through all the Word documents and look for the original path and update the root of the path to the new path.

I have searched everywhere I can think of and have not been able to find anything that helps me on this.

I have the following code just as a start to find the information that needs updating but nothing in this code gives me the path to the Excel data file where the mail merge data is coming from.

```
$OurDocuments = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Apps\testing" -Filter "*.doc*" -Recurse
 
$Word = New-Object -ComObject word.application 
$Word.Visible = $false
 
$OurDocuments | ForEach-Object {
     $Document = $Word.documents.open($_.FullName)
     "Processing file: {0}" -f $Document.FullName

     "MailMerge {0}" -f $Document.MailMerge
     "DataSource {0}" -f $Document.MailMerge.DataSource
 
     $Document.Close() 
}
 
$Word.Quit()
```

The MailMerge & DataSource objects and their properties do not have any references to the link to the Excel data file for the mail merge. I've also looked at the $Document.WordOpenXML and there is no reference in there.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You can't easily fix the mail merge data source path name using the Word object model (i.e. $Document.MailMerge etc.). If all these documents are "modern"  .docx/.dotx/.docm/.dotm files then you may be able to do the fix, or find a fix, that unpacks the .docx (which is a .zip file) and replaces the mail merge data source path in the two places it is likely to occur in that file. Sorry, I don't have helpful code for that. If any of your documents are the old .doc format, that won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is the modern .docx format. I have dumped the XML already from the wdOpenXML property on the object model and not found anything there. I will try what you suggest and dive into the zip file.

Comment: I've now managed to find the links in the word\settings.xml file under the w:mailmerge XML tag. I will do some more digging to see how I might go about changing these settings programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the end which required the search and update of two of the xml files within the zip package of the Word document. See code below for example

```
Add-Type -Assembly  System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$RootPath = 'x:\pathToSearch'

$settingsFile= "word/settings.xml"
$relsFile    = "word/_rels/settings.xml.rels"

# ! IMPORTANT - These must all be in lower case for comparison purposes !!!!
$toReplace1  = 'y:\'

$replaceWith = 'z:\OtherPath\'

function updateSettings {
    param (
        $entry
    )

    # Open the settings file and read in the full string
    $reader  = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($entry.Open())
    $content = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Dispose()

    # Check if we need to update this document at all !
    $testContent = $content.ToLower()
    if ($testContent.Contains($toReplace1)) {

        # Check if the file has not already been processed and had the path replaced
        if (!$content.ToLower().Contains($replaceWith.ToLower())) {

            # Replace all three possible strings with the new path
            $content = $content -replace [regex]::Escape($toReplace1), $replaceWith

            # Write the new string back out to the settings file
            $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($entry.Open())
            $writer.BaseStream.SetLength(0)
            $writer.Write($content)
            $writer.Flush()
            $writer.Close()
            $writer.Dispose()

            Write-Host "  Updated", $entry.FullName
        }
    }

}

cls

Write-Host "Starting"

Measure-Command {

    # List of top level folders to process so that we can at least see some progress
    $folders = Get-ChildItem -path $RootPath -Directory | Select-Object FullName
    Write-Host "Found", $folders.Count, "folders to process"

    # Loop through each folder
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {

        Write-Host "Processing folder", $folder.FullName

        # Get list of Word documents in this folder and all sub-folders
        $files = Get-ChildItem -path $folder.FullName -Recurse -Filter *.docx

        Write-Host "Found", $files.Count, "documents to process"

        # Loop through all files found
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            try {

                Write-Host "Checking file", $file.FullName         
             
                # if (-not (Test-Path ("$($File.DirectoryName)/_$($File.Name)") ) -and $($File.Name) -notmatch "^_" ) {
                #     Copy-Item "$($File.FullName)" "$($File.DirectoryName)/_$($File.Name)"
                # }

                # Open the document as a zip file
                $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($file.FullName, "Update")

                # Find the settings file(s) - Should only be one
                $entries = $zip.Entries.Where({ $_.FullName -eq $settingsFile })
                foreach($settingsEntry in $entries) {
                    updateSettings $settingsEntry
                }

                # Find the settings rel file(s) - Should only be one
                $entries = $zip.Entries.Where({ $_.FullName -eq $relsFile })
                foreach($relsEntry in $entries) {
                    updateSettings $relsEntry
                }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
                continue
            }
            finally {
                if($zip) {
                    $zip.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```